Why is my table only scrollable when I make it disappear and then reappear?
I have a data table that adds values to itself when a player clicks a specific button. I have this css for my table and all my seperate table classes.
table {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
.tableHeader {
  background-color: #4d4b4b;
}
.dataTable{
  display: table;
  height: 586.1px;
  width: 263.3px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.tableHolder {
  width: 280px;
  height: 602.8px;
  text-align: left;
}
.tableDropDown {
  width: 263.3px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 10px;
}


I am having an issue where the data table is only scrolling when I update using the .tableDropDown (which is a button that makes the table disappear or reappear). Otherwise, it just extends farther down the web page.
I have tried making the tableHolder scrollable (tableHolder is a div), but what happens then is that it works just fine until I use the tableDropDown. Then, a weird effect is made where the data table is a scrollable object inside of another scrollable object, which is obviously not what I want. Any help would be well appreciated!

Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your HTML and Javascript as well, preferably as a stack snippet which demonstrates the problem.
